# Why did the protein structure prediction accuracy in terms of GDT-TS decrease from 2008 (CASP 8) to 2014 (CASP 11)?

Tags: proteins, protein-structure, protein-folding

I read on https://doi.org/10.1038/d41586-020-03348-4:

[image]

Why did the protein structure prediction accuracy in terms of [GDT-TS (Global Distance Test — Total Score)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_distance_test) decrease from 2008 (CASP 8) to 2014 (CASP 11)?

Comment: A guess is that the tests given in the competition are of bigger proteins or the organisers have more of a pool to select challenging ones from because of the process getting cheaper in dollar terms. These proteins may be harder to model because of there being more pairwise force interactions between residues, so the average (y axis) will decrease for more difficult to model proteins unless better modelling can compensate for this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the historical details of computational challenge rather than a biological problem itself. As such it is, in my opinion, off-topic here, but is probably on-topic for SE Bioinformatics.